# How can I add ID and inputs array to my state?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, input, state

I'm trying to update my state which is :

```
inputData: {
    id: '',
    inputArr: ['']
}
```

From a form I'm getting from my state and I generate him like so :

```
inner = arr.input.map((inputs, index) => (
    <li key={index} name={index} id={inputs.id}>
        <label>{inputs.inputLabel}</label>
        <input
            // value={inputs.inputValue}
            type={inputs.inputType}
            onChange={this.handleChangeInp}
        />
    </li>
))
```

It will have mulitple inputs, so I wish to add all their inputs in the array by the order so i can extract it later, but my handleChange function doesn't seem to work, anyone know why (I cant get the ID that I'm passing with the event, nor to update the array)?

```
handleChangeInp = e => {
    const id = e.target.id;
    console.log(`the id is ${id}`);
    const index = Number(e.target.name);
    const inputData = this.state.inputData.inputArr.map((ing, i) => {
        console.log(i);
        i == index ? e.target.value : ing;
    });
}
```

thanks for the help!

Comment: The one question you ask that we need more data to answer regards updating your array, `inputData`. Are you expecting your array simply to be a list of integers (i.e. indices)?

Comment: InputData its just three strings that I put inside the label, type and value tags, do they really have anything to do with the problem I'm talking about?

Comment: Yes. When you use the `map` function, you are replacing the contents of an array with a new set of data. Look at your `handleChangeInp` function. You map over inputData and where the `index` equals `i`, you replace with a single string `e.target.value`.

Answer (score 0):

`e.target` will reference to the element and to get its props, like id, name, etc. you all need to have the props on the element itself.

To get the id, you'll need to pass the id props:

```
<input
  id={inputs.id}
  type={inputs.inputType}
  onChange={this.handleChangeInp}
/>
```

Now, `e.target.id` will get the inputs id. To get the name, do the same as above.

In this example, `e.target` is `<input />` element. And to get its properties, you just need to add the props.

Comment: how do I write that? and why props? i'm passing via event

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution is simple. Instead of putting the `id` and `name` attribute on the `li` element, add it to the `input`. This should allow you to get `name` from `e.target`.

**UPDATED: Based on additional research:**

The Synthetic `onChange` event in React does not pass the `id` attribute along. You need to come up with another solution. If you need to keep both the name and index of the input within an array, you can combined them with a special character and split them in the event handler. Looking back on some forms I have created, I see that I found it easy to use the pipe character `|`, since it is usually not used, but even still, I know it will be the last pipe in my string.

**Updated Map of Inputs Array**

```
inner = arr.input.map((inputs, index) => {
    console.log({inputs});
    return (
        <li key={index}>
            <label>{inputs.inputLabel}</label>
            <input
                name={inputs.id + "|" + index} 
                value={inputs.inputValue} /* try not commenting this out */
                type={inputs.inputType}
                onChange={this.handleChangeInp}
            />
        </li>
    )
});
```

**Updated onChange handler**

```
handleChangeInp = e => {
    const name = e.target.name.split("|");
    // index will be last element of array, pop it off
    const index = Number(name.pop());
    // join the name array back with the pipe character just in case it's used in the name 
    const id = name.join("|");
    console.log(`the id is ${id}`);
    console.log(`the index is ${index}`);
    const inputData = this.state.inputData.inputArr.map((ing, i) => {
        console.log(i);
        i == index ? e.target.value : ing;
    });
}
```

Comment: I changed it to the Input and it still doesn't work, I get ID as undefined in the function =\

Comment: I've updated. You need to see the data you are passing to the map function to verify you are getting the values you expect. I added a `console.log` to the `map` function so you can see the value of `inputs`. Perhaps the data structure is different than you expect.

Comment: After that, just to be thorough, in your `handleChangeInp` function, log the value of `e` so you can view all the event data.

Comment: the id s still undefined :(

Comment: What was the value of `inputs` in the console?

Comment: The inputs is just the name of the type label and value I add to the input tag, they work because I can see the input on my browser, I just cant seem to use the input itself.

Comment: You are assuming that it's working. Did you add the console.log statement, open your dev tools and see the value of the log in the console? Also, where are you getting `arr.input` that you are mapping over?

Comment: because I can see it on my page, I can see the values in the console, it works 100%, plus it has no effect whatsoever on the event i'm passing to the functions, does it?

Comment: It would have an effect if `inputs` was not an object with `id`, `inputLabel`, `inputValue`, and `inputType` properties. We can't see all of your code, we're trying to help you debug, so we have to ask questions.

Comment: I think part of the problem also is that you have `value` commented out on your input. For this to be a proper controlled component, you need to be setting value via props. I edited my response accordingly.

Comment: Alrighty Alex, sorry for taking so long, but based on additional research, I found that by default, the synthetic onchange event does not pass the id. Once solution, if you want both the index and the id to be passed to the hander is to concatenate the two values with a special character and then split the values into the two within the change handler. I updated my answer, and this should work.

Comment: Ok I got your point, you code doesnt work tho, but I will use split, thank you!

Comment: What doesn't work? Do you not see the values now? Or is your map function not working inside you event handler? That is where there seems to be some confusion in your code

Answer (score 0):

First update:

Proper parameters for generated inputs:

```
let inner = arr.input.map((inputs, index) => (
  <li key={index} >
    <label>{inputs.inputLabel}</label>
    <input
      id={index}
      name={inputs.id}
      // value={inputs.inputValue}
      type={inputs.inputType}
      onChange={this.handleChangeInp}
    />
  </li>
))
```

This way we'll have `id` and `name` available in event but **deep state structure** forces us to write sth like this:

```
handleChangeInp = e => {
  const id = e.target.id;
  console.log(`the id is ${id}`);
  const index = Number(e.target.id);
  // deep state update
  const newInputArr = this.state.inputData.inputArr.map((ing, i) => {
    console.log(i, e.target.name);
    return (i == index) ? e.target.value : ing;
  });
  const newInputData = {...this.state.inputData, inputArr: newInputArr}
  this.setState({ inputData: newInputData }, ()=>{console.log(this.state.inputData)})
}
```

It ['works'](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-vwkpza?file=index.js) ... **but this method of state update has 2 issues/drawbacks**:

1. values are stored in array by index - we have only index-value pairs;
2. the second issue is more serious - **it stores only first value!** For map usage ('searching') we should have array initialized for each index - otherwise it doesn't store values.

My advise - use object (map) to store values:

```
this.state = {
  inputData: {
    id: '',
    inputArr: {}
  }
};
```

and handler like this:

```
handleChangeInp = e => {
  const {name, value} = e.target;
  console.log(name, value);
  // deep state update
  const newInputArr = {...this.state.inputData.inputArr,[name]:value};
  const newInputData = {...this.state.inputData, inputArr: newInputArr}

  this.setState({ inputData: newInputData }, ()=>{console.log(this.state.inputData)})
}
```

This way we have id-value pairs and only for 'touched' fields.

Working [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-zqe93w?file=index.js).

Of course value for inputs can be read from state (if defined):

```
value={this.state.inputData.inputArr[inputs.id] 
  ? this.state.inputData.inputArr[inputs.id] : ''}

// or
value={this.state.inputData.inputArr[inputs.id]===undefined ? '' 
  : this.state.inputData.inputArr[inputs.id] }
// f.e. when we're using type conversions 
// and numerical value `0` could be used as valid input
```